# Can anything be done to get newest Word for Mac to open documents in full-sized windows?

Tags: microsoft-word

In version 16.25 (19050200), a new document opens in a small window, which must be resized to be big enough to display all Ribbon tabs, etc. Saving the document after resizing it fixes this but it's super annoying. Anything that can be done to change this default behavior?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I reported the problem using the "sad face" function within Word. I got an email back from Microsoft telling me it was a bug and a fix was in the works. Version 16.26 (19060901) seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for following up and closing the loop on your question :) For those who might be interested, can you [edit] your answer to include a source for what you say? Cheers!